# go mysql LAST_INSERT_ID() returns 0

Tags: mysql, sql, go, last-insert-id

I have this MySQL database where I need to add records with a go program and need to retrieve the id of the last added record, to add the id to another table.

When i run insert `INSERT INTO table1 values("test",1);  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` in MySQL Workbench, it returns the last id, which is auto incremented, with no issues.

If I run my go code however, it always prints 0. The code:

```
    _, err := db_client.DBClient.Query("insert into table1 values(?,?)", name, 1)
    var id string
    err = db_client.DBClient.QueryRow("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()").Scan(&id)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println("id: ", id)
```

I tried this variation to try to narrow down the problem scope further: `err = db_client.DBClient.QueryRow("SELECT id from table1 where name=\"pleasejustwork\";").Scan(&id)`, which works perfectly fine; go returns the actual id.

Why is it not working with the LAST_INSERT_ID()?

I'm a newbie in go so please do not go hard on me if i'm making stupid go mistakes that lead to this error :D

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *Why is it not working with the LAST_INSERT_ID()?* 99% that some intermediate queries are sent to MySQL hiddenly, or 2nd query is executed in another connection. Execute both queries in single transaction.

Comment: ok, but how would you solve this problem? I need the id of the query, and I think I can not put 2 queries in one function call

Comment: Maybe https://go.dev/doc/database/execute-transactions ?

Comment: Im just learning sql. Could you explain the difference between a transaction (Tx), which you're suggesting to look into, and a database handle (DB), which I was using so far?

Comment: Using `Query` and discarding, i.e. assigning to `_`, the primary return value, will cause a resource leak. For queries that don't return any rows you SHOULD use the `Exec` method. Also the `Exec` method returns an `sql.Result` value which, if implemented by the 3rd party driver you are using, will provide you the last inserted id through the `LastInsertedId` method.

Comment: Also note that the DB handle in Go is a *pool* of connections and it's quite possible that the two separate queries were executed using two different connections from the pool. And, as far as mysql is concerned, the `ID` that was generated by AUTO_INCREMENT is maintained in the server on a **per-connection basis**. This means that the value returned by the function LAST_INSERT_ID is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent insert statement executed using the **same** connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL protocol returns `LAST_INSERT_ID()` values in its response to `INSERT` statements. And, the golang driver exposes that returned value. So, you don't need the extra round trip to get it.  These ID values are usually unsigned 64-bit integers.

Try something like this.

```golang
    res, err := db_client.DBClient.Exec("insert into table1 values(?,?)", name, 1)
     if err != nil {
        panic (err.Error())
    }
    id, err := res.LastInsertId()
    if err != nil {
        panic (err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println("id: ", id)
```

I confess I'm not sure why your code didn't work.  Whenever you successfully issue a single-row INSERT statement, the next statement on the same database connection *always* has access to a useful `LAST_INSERT_ID()` value. This is true whether or not you use explicit transactions.

But if your `INSERT` is not successful, you must treat the last insert ID value as *unpredictable.* (That's a technical term for "garbage", trash, rubbish, basura, etc.)